# REGEX validação de senha

Tags: java, regex

Tenho um problema de Validação e não consigo aplicar dentro de uma estrutura simples, 3 validações não pode ter alfanuméricos  decrescentes, crescentes e nem repetidos numa mesma senha.

> Por exemplo: 00000000 , 01234567 , 98765432 , aaaaaaaa, aa1123456

alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Se eu fosse seu usuário, iria agradecer se não restringisse a senha (ainda mais nesse nível). Boa sorte.

Comment: Quantos caracteres repetidos será considerados para dizer que a senha tenha que estra nessa validação, por exemplo a senha aa123r56, seria valida? sua senha sempre vai ser composta por 8 caracteres?

Comment: a senha aa123r56 não seria válida por existir uma sequencia  repetição em aa e 123 na mesma senha a principio sim seria 8 caracteres possivelmente irão aumentar o valor do campo.

usei uma solução anterior mas, não me atendeu bem, por conta da documentação.

Comment: Parece que detectar sequências usando regex não é possível. Veja este tópico no SOen, pode ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880088/regular-expression-to-match-3-or-more-consecutive-sequential-characters-and-cons

Comment: Pelo que conheço, não é possível detectar sequência de números com _regex_. É possível detectar números ou letras repetidos, como `000` ou `aaa`, mas uma sequência `123`, `987` ou `abc` não.

Comment: Quer disser que se meu ano de nascimento fosse 1987 eu não poderia usar ele por ser sequencia?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que conheço, não é viável detectar sequência de números com *`regex`*.
É possível detectar caracteres repetidos facilmente, como 000 ou aaa, mas uma sequência 123, 987 ou abc não.

O *`regex`* por si só, não atribui valor aos caracteres. Ele **não** identifica que `2` é maior que `1` ou que `b` é seguido de `a` no alfabeto.
Para fazer isso você teria que escrever todas as sequências possíveis para ele dar *match* em alguma delas. Como exemplo a *pattern* "`123|12|23|321|32|21`" para identificar uma sequência simples entre três números.

Para letras ou números repetidos você poderia usar um *pattern* que procura por ocorrências repetidas como "`(\d|\w)\1+`".
Nesse caso o *pattern* obtém uma letra ou número e logo em seguida verifica se ele se repete uma ou mais vezes.
Veja funcionando no [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jO9rP4/1).